# Swift 3, get one value from JSON

Tags: json, swift

I'm new to Swift 3 and have been trying for ages to do the following.
I have a JSON response like this:

```
Optional({
    "USD_ILS" =     {
        val = "3.5989";
    };
})
```

Here is where I make the request:

```
func makeRequest(){
    Alamofire.request("http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v3/convert?q=USD_ILS&compact=y").responseJSON { response in
        print(response.result.value)   // result of response serialization

        let data = JSON(response.result.value)
        print(data)

        let val = data["val"].stringValue
        print(val)
    }
}
```

All I want to do is get the 'val' field to a variable, like String (or Double). I'm now using SwiftyJSON, but still don't know what to do after this:

```
let data = JSON(response.result.value)
```

Comment: There are countless examples about how to use `JSONSerialization` in Swift to parse JSON. Update your question with what you have tried and clearly explain what issue you having.

Comment: let data = JSON(response.result.value) using SwiftyJSON library

Comment: Glenn, I followed your adivce, but still a bit stuck. I edited my answer. Could you still help? Thanks

Comment: `data` is a Swift dictionary. You now need to traverse its keys and values to dig down to the value you actually want.

Comment: You've got at least to get to the first level: `data["USD_ILS"]`, then from that (which is a dict) `dataUSD["val"]`.

Comment: maddy and larme, thanks very much.

Comment: data["USD_ILS"]["val"].stringValue would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this without using any JSON API: (Tested)

```
func makeRequest(){
    Alamofire.request("http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v3/convert?q=USD_ILS&compact=y").responseJSON { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            if let dict = JSON as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
                if let value = dict["USD_ILS"] as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
                    if let val = value["val"] as? Double {
                        print(val)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's how you navigate through a JSON. What was Happening, is that you have a dictionary inside a Dictionary, that make it a little more "Complex" to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way using `SwiftyJSON`:

```
let data = JSON(response.result.value)

guard let value = data["USD_ILS"]["val"].string else {
        return
}

print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
func getStringFromJSON(json: Any, key: String, defaultValue: String) -> String {
    if let j = json as? [String : AnyObject] {
        if let returnString = j[key] as? String {
            return returnString
        }
    }

    return defaultValue
}
```